# How do I farm the Sand Hawk optimally?

Tags: borderlands-2

While looking for ways to farm the Sand Hawk, I came across this [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Nz6d2eDd7Zg). It says that the Sand Hawk can drop from Benny the Booster if the Community Patch is installed. I am playing on PS5 and am not sure what this patch is and how to install it.

Is there a good way to farm Sandhawk that does not take a lifetime?

Comment: It is stated in the video that the community patch is for PC only.

Comment: is there a better way to farm it then, instead of reloading entire playthrough ? i have already accepted the mission reward at lvl 79. i am lvl 80 now.

Comment: I found this: https://www.reddit.com/r/Borderlands2/comments/arjjrb/farming_multiple_sandhawks_on_ps4_will_this_work/ which appears to work (under certain conditions) on PS4, the same may apply to PS5...

Comment: i saw that but unfortuanetely I found it after i had done step 4 already. i already turned in the "whoops" quest. guess i am doomed :/

Comment: @VipinVerma FYI, you should be able to reset your mission progression in UVHM if you don’t mind re-doing some missions, you can re-do the mission and do the method described in that Reddit post. Downside is you’re resetting **all** mission progress